# remove other postgres database servers

Tags: postgresql

```
$ sudo service postgresql restart
 * Restarting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server
   ...done.
 * Restarting PostgreSQL 9.5 database server
   ...done.
 * Restarting PostgreSQL 9.6 database server
   ...done.
```

I currently use 9.5 only..

What should I do to remove other versions (9.3, 9.6) so that only single instance runs when I do `service postgresql restart`

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall them  with

```
sudo apt-get remove postgresql-9.3
sudo apt-get remove postgresql-9.6
```

Answer (score 0):

if the 
`sudo apt-get remove postgresql-9.3
sudo apt-get remove postgresql-9.6`
doesn't work try 
`sudo apt purge postgresql-9.3
sudo apt purge postgresql-9.6`
This will remove everything related to those two installs.